# Pass dynamic path via API-Gateway to AWS-Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm running a Flask-application on AWS-Lambda based on this tutorial:
https://andrewgriffithsonline.com/blog/180412-deploy-flask-api-any-serverless-cloud-platform/#create-flask-app

My problem now is that this setup works absolutely fine for the defined home-path ("/"), but whenever I call e.g. "/user/7" the API-Gatway returns 403, since it doesn't know the route, although it is defined in the Flask-Lambda.

Is there a possibility to setup API-Gateway in a way to pass the whole request through to the Lambda, regardless of whatever path the request has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `{proxy+}` path to act as a catch all for API Gateway.

By creating the [proxy resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html) anything that matches the prefix will automatically use that resource, if you add it to the root resource then it will process all other requests that do not match a specific URL pattern.

You could also use variables in your path resource names, for your user method for example the path would end up being `/user/{userId}`. This is the **preferable** solution as it is still being specific to the request type.

More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html).